# Почему при создании компонента во Vue 2 нужно инкапсулировать все элементы в родительский тег (например div)

Tags: vue.js

Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь кинет годную ссылку на объяснение, почему во Vue 2 при создании компонента нужно помещать все элементы в родительский тег, иначе будет ошибка.

Например:

```
<template>
 <div> <!-- Родительский тег-->
  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>World</p>
 </div>
</template>
```

Comment: С одной стороны может автору vue так проще, а с другой пользователю не составит никакого труда заключить всё в даже лишний тэг.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что каждый компонент должен иметь один корневой элемент. Тег template не является элементом.

https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82